# how can i search all data in datatables yajra

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-datatables

i try to use yajra datatables laravel
i have problem in searching
when i search data already exits in datatables it no working
me already try example in documentation but it not working for me

can someone please help me?
teach me how to do like i mean

[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFxhp.png)
[example searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q3Na.png)

** this is my javascript datatables**

```
let oTable = $("#example1").DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax:
        {
            url: '{{ route("data.user.datatables") }}',
            type: 'GET',
            data: function (d) {
                d.filter = $('select[name=filter]').val();
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'id'},
            { data: function(data, type, row){
                return 'Username : ' + data.username +
                '<br> Email : ' + data.email +
                '<br> Ponsel : ' + data.contact_number;
            },
            name: 'username'
            },
            {
            data: function(data, type, row){
                return 'Register Date : ' +  data.created_at +
                        '<br> Last Login : ' + data.last_login +
                        '<br> App By : '+ data.app_admin +' / '+ data.date_admin_app +
                        '<br> App By : '+ data.login +' || '+ data.status_member;
            },

             name: 'created_at'
            },
            { data: function(data, type, row){
                return 'Saldo : ' +  data.saldo +
                    '<br> Bank Name : ' + data.bank_name +
                    '<br> Account Name : '+ data.account_name +
                    '<br> Account Number : '+ data.account_number;
            },
            name:'saldo'
            },
            { data: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
        ],
        order:[[0,'desc']],

    });
```

**this in my Laravel CONTROLLER**

```
if($request->ajax()):

            $request->validate([
                'filter' => ['string','nullable','alpha'],
            ]);

            if($request->filled('filter')):
                $users = User::query()->where('status_member', $request->filter);
            else:
                $users = User::query();
            endif;
            $data =  Datatables::of($users);
             $data->addIndexColumn();
             $data->addColumn('action', function ($user) {
                return '<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action</button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item modal-edit-user" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditUser" href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="' . $user->id . '" data-username="' . $user->username . '" >Edit</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>';
            });
            $data->rawColumns(['action']);
            return $data->make();
        endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are forwarding nothing at all to user query.

Instead of

```
$users = User::query()->where('status_member', $request->filter);
...
$users = User::query();
```

try doing

```
$users = User::where('status_member', $request->filter)->get();
...
$users = User::all();
```

EDIT:

update your code:

```
{ data: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
```

to

```
{ data: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: true}
```

Comment: thanks for your answare, but i mean i can search contact_number too etc.. in search input datatables

Comment: I see searchable is set to false. Set it to true

Comment: searchable just false in row action but in another row it is true

Comment: Where is "another row"?

Comment: Sure, but you are still attaching a table with searchable:false to your element.

Comment: still not working, i think the problem is in the query i use datatables yajra laravel

Answer (score 0):

> You can extract the level filter on the query level to make this work like this:

1. Draw the table again on the Dropdown Change

   ```
   let oTable = $("#example1").DataTable({
   responsive: true,
   autoWidth: false,
   processing: true,
   serverSide: true,
   ajax:
   {
       url: '{{ route("data.user.datatables") }}',
       type: 'GET',
       data: function (d) {
           d.filter = $('select[name=filter]').val();
       }
   },
   columns: [
       { data: 'id'},
       { data: function(data, type, row){
           return 'Username : ' + data.username +
           '<br> Email : ' + data.email +
           '<br> Ponsel : ' + data.contact_number;
       },
       name: 'username'
       },
       {
       data: function(data, type, row){
           return 'Register Date : ' +  data.created_at +
                   '<br> Last Login : ' + data.last_login +
                   '<br> App By : '+ data.app_admin +' / '+ data.date_admin_app +
                   '<br> App By : '+ data.login +' || '+ data.status_member;
       },

        name: 'created_at'
       },
       { data: function(data, type, row){
           return 'Saldo : ' +  data.saldo +
               '<br> Bank Name : ' + data.bank_name +
               '<br> Account Name : '+ data.account_name +
               '<br> Account Number : '+ data.account_number;
       },
       name:'saldo'
       },
       { data: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
   ],
   order:[[0,'desc']],

   });

   //Add these lines here
   $('select[name=filter]').change(function(){
   oTable.draw();
   });
   ```
2. Filter the result by query

   ```
   if($request->ajax()):

       $request->validate([
           'filter' => ['string','nullable','alpha'],
       ]);
       $filter = $request->filter;

       $users = User::select('*')
       ->when($filter, function($query) use ($filter) { 
           return $query->where('status_member', '=', $filter);
         })
       ->get();


       $data =  Datatables::of($users);
        $data->addIndexColumn();
        $data->addColumn('action', function ($user) {
           return '<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
                       <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                           <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action</button>
                           <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
                               <a class="dropdown-item modal-edit-user" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditUser" href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="' . $user->id . '" data-username="' . $user->username . '" >Edit</a>
                               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>';
       });
       $data->rawColumns(['action']);
       return $data->make();
   endif;
   ```